# How to send Firebase Analytics data ONLY when wi-fi is on?

Tags: android, android-wifi, firebase-analytics

Hello all :) I know that events from app which uses Firebase Analytics are stored localy, then after some time, they are sent to console on-line. I want the data to be sent only, when wi-fi on the device is available. Is that even possible? Thank You all in advance!

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow :-)
What have you tried so far? Please look at [ask]
and how to create a [mcve]. This will help to get useful answers.

Comment: Hi :) I didn't even found similar problem to mine, so I'm totally open for anything. Need to send Firebase Analytics data only via Wi-Fi.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, wifi only upload is not possible. In order to ensure reliable data uploads without excessive battery stress the data uploading is always automatic. For example on Android data from multiple apps is batches and uploaded together in order to minimize the number of times the device has to wake up the network (very costly operation from battery use perspective). Allows each app to define when and how it wants to upload the data prevents devices wide optimizations.

Uploading only over wifi will also result in inaccurate reports as it allows for significant number of the devices to upload data with significant delay and therefore be excluded from the active users and other calculation.

Comment: Thank You for answer.

Comment: Well, some users have metered cellular plans,
https://github.com/sky-map-team/stardroid/issues/165
thus would not participate if participating cost them their cell allowance or increased their cell fees.